# What is the Spark SQL statement for seeing the version of Spark processing the query?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have access to a web tool that executes Spark SQL queries, and I need to check the version of Spark processing those queries (e.g., 3.1?). Is there a Spark SQL statement that I can run which will return the version of Spark, and possibly other information?

- I looked through the docs, but I didn't see anything.
- I don't have another way to determine this information, such as running `spark-sql --version`. I'm limited to this web interface that accepts valid Spark SQL.
- Does Spark offer something like MySQL's `SHOW VARIABLES` [statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-variables.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an SQL function that returns the Spark version in the [Misc Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#misc-functions) section:

> `version()` - Returns the Spark version. The string contains 2 fields, the first being a release version and the second being a git revision.

Usage is:

```
spark-sql> SELECT version();
3.1.2 de351e30a90dd988b133b3d00fa6218bfcaba8b8
Time-taken: 0.087 seconds, Fetched 1 row(w)
```

Comment: Looked only for the query statements but it is in the funtions! cool.

Answer (score 1):

There is no info about spark version, but once you set the confg for the spark session then you can see it by query. This can be editable by user I think..

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .config('spark.version', '3.3.1') \
  .getOrCreate()

spark.sql('set spark.version').show()
+-------------+-----+
|          key|value|
+-------------+-----+
|spark.version|3.3.1|
+-------------+-----+
```

Comment: I ran `SET -v` and looked through the output. In my case, the final command was `SET spark.binary`,  which got me the information I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Why rely on user-settable properties when there is a built-in function that returns the Spark version?